# How to create a grid cell and average point data per each cell in R?

Tags: r

I have a a big dataframe with latitude, longitude and different variables for each point. It looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame = (plot = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
latitude =c(48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50),
longitude = c(7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9),
class = c(0,2,0,1,1,3,1,1,0,0,2,1,2,0,1))
```

For now I used `ggplot` and `ggmap` to plot this and the map looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a grid cell instead and then average all the plots within one cell, but with a minimum threshold of number of plots per cell. I guess the starting point is to use `raster` but I am not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand well. If you want to create a raster with the mean value of the vector of a point based on a threshold, you can simply do something like this (using your data as an example, but adding another plot that do not meet the threshold):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(terra)
df <- data.frame (plot = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D"),
                    lat =c(48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,51),
                    lon = c(7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,10),
                    class = c(0,2,0,1,1,3,1,1,0,0,2,1,2,0,1,1))

threshold <- 3
newdf <- df %>% group_by(plot) %>% summarise(lat=unique(lat),lon=unique(lon),class=ifelse(n()<threshold,NA,mean(class)))
newdf <- newdf[,c(3,2,4)]
v <- vect(newdf)
plot(v)
r <- rast(newdf)
plot(r,fun=function()points(v))
```